# How to remove entire div with preg_replace

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

Ok, as it is WordPress problem and it sadly goes a little deeper, I need to remove each representation of parent div and its inside:

```
<div class="sometestclass">
   <img ....>
   <div>.....</div>
   any other html tags
</div><!-- END: .sometestclass -->
```

The only idea I have is to match everything that starts with:

```
<div class="sometestclass">
```

and ends with:

```
<!-- END: .sometestclass -->
```

with all that is between (I can tag the end of parent div anyway I want, this is just a sample).
Anybody have an idea how to do it with:

```
<?php $content = preg_replace('?????','',$content); ?>
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex, nanananana.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/333786)

Comment: I know, i know, str_replace I should use ;)

Comment: Ok, I should not, I get the joke ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regular expression. Instead, I would use the [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. Just find all of the `div` elements with that class, and remove them from their parent(s):

```
$html = "<p>Hello World</p>
         <div class='sometestclass'>
           <img src='foo.png'/>
           <div>Bar</div>
         </div>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='sometestclass']");

foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
  $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
}

echo preg_replace( "/.*<body>(.*)<\/body>.*/s", "$1", $dom->saveHTML() );
```

Which results in:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Sadly I have no idea about it :(.
Could You explain with some kind of sample?

Comment: Instead of cycling over all divs, he could use an XPath query, to directly find divs with the right class.

Comment: @JonathanSampson this example gives me an idea about how to do it, but it depends on a parent (not named) div. But what, if I would not have that parent div, and needed to finish with only <p>Hello World</p> ?

Comment: so the input html is: <p>Hello World</p>
           <div class='sometestclass'>
             <img src='foo.png'/>
             <div>Bar</div>
           </div>

Comment: Ok, I get it, after few tries it almost works. Only problem is with encoding - it does something strange with utf-8 encoded local language characters :(

Comment: @MarcinBobowski You can set encoding in the constructor: `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');`

Comment: @JonathanSampson - already tryied, setting utf-8, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2 doesnt help. My country special chars like ąęśćź changes to iÄ™ Å‚ Å¼ etc.

Comment: @JonathanSampson. Thanks for this good answer. What is the `$1`? Id there another way of saving back, without using preg_replace?

Comment: @Arash The `$1` refers to the `(.*)` in the regular expression.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thanks for response. could you please translate the preg_replace line in english?

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php $content = preg_replace('/<div class="sometestclass">.*?<\/div><!-- END: .sometestclass -->/s','',$content); ?>
```

My RegEx is a bit rusty, but I think this should work. Do note that, as others have said, RegEx is not properly equipped to handle some of the complexities of HTML.

In addition, this pattern won't find embedded `div` elements with the class `sometestclass`. You would need recursion for that.

Comment: This might work, but already I have used DOMDocument method. But thanks for RegEx, its more easy to learn on examples :)

Answer (score 0):

How about just some CSS `.sometestclass{display: none;}` ?

Comment: Hiding html element is not good idea as per SEO Experts, many prefer removing elements to save html size.

Answer (score 0):

For the UTF-8 issue, I found a hack at the [PHP-manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251)

So my functions looks as follows:

```
function rem_fi_cat() {
/* This function removes images from _within_ the article.
 * If these images are enclosed in a "wp-caption" div-tag.
 * If the articles are post formatted as "image".
 * Only on home-page, front-page an in category/archive-pages.
 */
if ( (is_home() || is_front_page() || is_category()) && has_post_format( 'image' ) ) {
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $content = get_the_content( '', true );
    if( '' != $content ) {
        /* incl. UTF-8 "hack" as described at 
         * http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251
         */
        $document->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $content );
        foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item) {
            if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE) {
                $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
                $doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper
            }
        }
        $xpath = new DOMXPath( $document );
        $pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='wp-caption']");

        foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
            $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
        }

        echo preg_replace( "/.*<div class=\"entry-container\">(.*)<\/div>.*/s", "$1", $document->saveHTML() );

    }
}
```

}