# Remove entire div tag contents turn into a function

Tags: php, function, html

What I'm seeking to do is find an elegant solution to remove the contents of everything between a certain  class = i.e. you want to remove all the HTML in the sometestclass class using php.

The function below works somewhat - not that well - it removes some parts of the page I don't want removed.
Below is a function based on an original post (below):

```
$html = "<p>Hello World</p>
         <div class='sometestclass'>
           <img src='foo.png'/>
           <div>Bar</div>
         </div>";
$clean = removeDiv ($html,'sometestclass');
echo $clean;

function removeDiv ($html,$removeClass){
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$removeString = ".//div[@class='$removeClass']";
$pDivs = $xpath->query($removeString);

foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
  $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
}

$output = preg_replace( "/.*<body>(.*)<\/body>.*/s", "$1", $dom->saveHTML() );
return $output;
}
```

does anyone have any suggestions to improve the results of this?

[the original post is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658770/how-to-remove-entire-div-with-preg-replace)

Comment: Do you want to remove the content of all divs? Or just divs with a specified class?

Comment: I just want to remove a comment box from a BLOG - its enclosed in a <div class='commentBox'>  lots of stufff    </div>

so what i'm really looking for is a simpler way to do this. It would scan the file for the first instance of the 'commentbox' class and then remove everything including all the other nested <divs> in between it. 
Does that make sense? I don't want to touch the rest of the page and I believe the <div class='commentBox'> only appears ONCE on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You are not quoting the class name:

```
$removeString = ".//div[@class=$removeClass]";
```

should be:

```
$removeString = ".//div[@class='$removeClass']";
```

Comment: that worked... thanks... the code is still buggy - it works for very simple HTML but it creates warnings then I run it for real on a page.

Comment: @Viktor What kind of warnings?

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 87 in /home/content/07/9157607/html/test.php on line 81


Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag g:plusone invalid in Entity, line: 174 in /home/content/07/9157607/html/test.php on line 81


those are the warnings - but it also removes the Google+1 button from the page when I run the script - I could suppress the warnings, but that problem still exists that it is altering other sections of the page.

Comment: @Viktor If your html is not valid, you could try to put it through for example Tidy or HTML Purifier.

Comment: Thanks but that's not an option. This function is part of a page rewriting script - we fetch the page from the web and fix the html. We're writing something like Tidy but it is specific to a blog that has a comment box that doesn't work. All we want to do is fetch the contents remove the comment box and be happily on our way.